# $y=0$ is singular solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=E(y)$ iff the improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{E(y)}$ is convergent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

Assume that a continuous function $E(y)$ is such that $$E(0)=0,~~~~E(y)\neq 0,~~~~0<y\le 1.$$ Then $y=0$ is the singular solution of the differential equation
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx}=E(y),
$$ 
if and only if the improper integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{dy}{E(y)}$$ 
is  convergent.

[image]

This problem is from china ODE problem (can see :http://item.jd.com/1048628556.html, page 111. problem 4, and I don't see any book have solution by this problem. Thank you

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of the desired pages? (I don't know Chinese at all.)

Comment: @GitGud,Now have you understand?

Comment: @math110 I still don't understand. You say "$y=0$ is differential equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=E(y)$". Do you mean to say that the constant function $\bf 0$ is a solution of $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=E(y)$?

Comment: I think I got it. Please try to understand if what's below is what you want to ask. $$\text{The constant function }\mathbf{0}\text{ is the only solution of }y'=E\circ y\text{ if, and only if, }\int \limits _0^1 \dfrac 1{E(y)}\mathrm dy\text{ converges}.$$

Comment: yes,That's you mean,But my problem is signular solution